# Synchronising function calls in two different ojet modules

Tags: javascript, jquery, oracle-jet

Need to synchronize two different calls in two different javascript pages that are putting the data into the same collection.

Example:

***JS Page 1***

```
self.customerColl(CustomerFactory.customerModel().getCustomer(self.customerId()));                 
self.customerColl().fetch().then(function () {                                                                         
         if(customer is not found){                                           
                    persist the customer in db
         }
});
```

***JS Page 2***

```
self.customerColl(CustomerFactory.customerModel().getCustomer(self.customerId()));                 
self.customerColl().fetch().then(function () {                                                                         
         if(customer is not found){
                    persist the customer in db
         }
});
```

Both the above ojet modules are loaded in the same index page. In that case, both the fetch in 2 different js files are getting executed one after other and both are trying to persist the data in db. One of them succeeds and the other fails. I want this operation to happen in coordination. Say JS Page 1 code executed and then the code for JS Page 2 executes.